# Different CRC32 values in Java and swift

Tags: swift, crc, crc32

I'm in the process of writing a utility in Swift which can be used to calculate CRC32 checksum of an input data . A similar utility exists in Java which we are using extensively and has been working well for us.

The Java Utility uses `java.util.zip.CRC32` to calculate the checksum. Pseudo code is as follows :

Java code:

```
private void transferFileData(short index, byte[] data, long dataSize) {  
    CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
        
    long crc = crc32.update(data, (int) dataSize);
     System.out.println("CRC32 : " + crc);
}
```

The Swift uses the CRC32   (import CryptoSwift) CryptoSwift code for generating the checksum in swift is as follows :

Swift code:

```
func crc32Func(_ item:[Int8] ) {
        let data = Data(bytes: item, count: item.count)
        let byte = data.bytes
        let crc32 = byte.crc32()
        print("checksum == \(crc32)"
}
```

The output from the Java code is :

`Checksum in Java : 3771181957`

The output from the swift code is :

`Checksum in swift : 1894162356`

Why the checksum values are not the same?

This is the code applied by Swift as below:

The data type is `[Int8]`

The data size is `450 bytes`.

let item:

> [Int8] =  [45, 35, 76, 70, 67, 68, 95, 70, 79, 84, 65, 95, 70, 87, 95,
> 70, 85, 76, 76, 10, 80, 75, 71, 95, 86 , 69, 82, 83, 73, 79, 78, 58,
> 51, 46, 48, 46, 48, 10, 66, 65, 83, 69, 95, 86, 69, 82, 83, 73, 79, 78
> , 58, 10, 72, 65, 83, 72, 58, 51, 97, 57, 98, 51, 99, 52, 56, 57, 52,
> 56, 56, 53, 49, 50, 53, 52, 55 , 48, 51, 49, 54, 48, 57, 56, 48, 101,
> 98, 101, 51, 54, 54, 10, 80, 75, 71, 95, 83, 73, 90, 69, 58, 49 , 51,
> 49, 48, 55, 50, 48, 10, 26, 0, 0, 5, 32, -79, 11, 5, 8, -39, -5, 4, 8,
> -35, -5, 4, 8, -15, -5, 4, 8, -13, -5, 4, 8, -11, -5, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -31, -15, 10, 8, -9, -5, 4, 8,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, -127, -14, 10, 8, -27, -14, 10, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5,
> 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1,
> 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12,
> 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8,
> -7, -5, 4, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 9, -4,
> 4, 8, 25, -4, 4, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5,
> 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 57, -4, 4, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 73, -4, 4, 8, 89, -4, 4, 8,
> 105, -4, 4, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, -39, -4, 4, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8,
> 1, 12, 5, 8, 41, -4, 4, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1,
> 12, 5 , 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 121, -4, 4, 8, -119, -4, 4, 8, 1,
> 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12,
> 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8,
> 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, 1, 12, 5, 8, -103, -4]

is input.

Java input:

`byte[]` data

The type is `long` and the data entered is the same as `[Int8]` of swift data.

Comment: Do not provide pseudo code. **Provide your actual code.** That first bit of Java makes no sense, as `update()` does not return a value, and takes either one or three arguments, _not_ two. The Swift code is also in error. You need to provide the example input data you are computing the CRC on. Make your example short, e.g. "123456789".

Comment: Besides what @MarkAdler says It would also be useful if you told us what the input is. What sequence of bytes gives the two checksums?

Comment: Ok, you added the data, but you have still not provided the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

The CRC you are getting from your Swift code (whatever that actual code is) is correct. The CRC you are getting from your Java code (whatever *that* actual code is) is not correct.

There is no way to know what you're doing wrong in your Java code without at least being able to see that code.

Comment: I am having a different weird problem, the same function i use to calculate crc32 generated different values in android 11 and android below 11!! do you have any clue?

Comment: @moumenShobakey You need to ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't love me :)